# Cisco 3850-24p stable firmware 16.x.x

Tags: cisco-ios, ios-xe, firmware, cisco-3850

Have a query towards the 3850 series switches.
Currently making a plan to upgrade a few remote sites from old, stable and steady 3650-24ps (eol awhile back) to 3850-24p.
Nothing fancy to support, 1 ospf instance, SVIs, portfast, DAI, 802.1s, VTPv3, dhcp services to local users, 802.3at, etc

Starting to have reservations on using the 3850 series due to the number of bugs and reports on instability with the latest Cisco ios.
Could go with a 3.x train for ios but they are apparently eol.

Has anyone had any luck with a stable 16.x.x firmware version?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, the software 16.3.6 is safe harbor and suggested by Cisco. We run it on more than 200 x 3850 and have not yet had any problems with the software. We are running BGP with normal layer 3 VLANs (SVI), portfast, DAI, access lists, QoS etc.

Screenshot from Cisco download center:
[image]

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the feedack. We were recommended by Cisco and looking at 16.6.4 but reading on the major bugs towards dhcp snooping, AVB, etc and comments on the www, I'd thought I'd better ask about the 16.x.x train. I'm setting a stack in a lab environment and will test before rolling out... some sites are over 3000Ks away and being stable is critical. Hope your production stack remains stable and bug free :-)

Comment: @user4565 feel free to accept the answer, so that it doesn't keep popping up. :-)

Comment: Clicked on it, should be good now :-)